# Why am i getting this error when running react app while using npm start?

Tags: reactjs

My Package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
```

My log File

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.15.5
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\samar/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
5 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:155:19)
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:63:5
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:116:5
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:436:5
5 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:391:45)
5 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:434:3)
5 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:161:5)
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:382:12
5 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:123:16
5 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:63:3)
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\samar\Desktop\React\learn
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.21318
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
9 verbose node v14.15.5
10 verbose npm  v6.14.11
11 error missing script: start
12 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Things I would check - make sure you're in the same directory in your terminal as the package.json.  Make sure you ran `npm install`.  Try `npm run start`.  Do any of those fix your problem?  Note these are 3 separate concepts, you don't necessarily need to do these in order (well maybe the directory location and `npm install` you do)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `package.json` file isn't in the correct location? This error usually means that there doesn't exist a "start" command. Make sure `package.json` is in the root directory then run `npm start`. Also use `npm install` to install all the required packages.